a Popup element is not scrolling with inner div when overflow
I'm using vanilla-calendar.pro and here is my simple code below:


          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const calendar = new VanillaCalendar('#calendar', {
                // Settings
                input: true,
                actions: {
                    changeToInput(e, self) {
                    if (!self.HTMLInputElement) return;
                    if (self.selectedDates[0]) {
                        self.HTMLInputElement.innerHTML = self.selectedDates[0];
                        // if you want to hide the calendar after picking a date
                        self.hide();
                    } else {
                        self.HTMLInputElement.textContent = '';
                    }
                    },
                },
                settings: {
                    visibility: {
                    positionToInput: 'center',
                    },
                },

            });
            calendar.init();
          });
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-calendar-pro/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-calendar-pro/build/vanilla-calendar.min.js" defer></script>
        <title>test page</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1 style =" font-size: 40px;" >Test Project</h1>

        <div style="height: 50rem; background-color: rgb(182, 142, 215); overflow-y: scroll; display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column;">
            
            <div style="margin-bottom: 90rem;" > some components 1</div>
            
            <input id="calendar" type="text" placeholder="Choose date" readonly />
            
            <div style="margin-bottom: 90rem;" > some components 2</div>

        </div>
 
      </body>
</html>



My problem is that when you click the input to choose a date and the calendar popup shows up, then when you try to scroll the inner div the popup calendar dose not scroll properly with it!.
I tried to contain it inside a div to see if it works but its not, also tried to set style
position: absolute/ relative or z-index here and there also its not working..
Any help with that please?

The fact is your calendar is placed according to the body, not your elements with scroll. So it's normal your calendar scroll too when you scroll in your div.
As a workaround, you can place the element inside your scrolling div, using the init action:
const calendar = new VanillaCalendar('#calendar', {
  // Settings
  input: true,
  actions: {
    initCalendar(self) {
      if (!self.HTMLElement) return;
      var wrapperElement = document.querySelector('#calendar-wrapper');
      self.HTMLElement.classList.add('top-0');
      wrapperElement.append(self.HTMLElement);
      
    }, 
    changeToInput(e, self) {
      if (!self.HTMLInputElement) return;
      if (self.selectedDates[0]) {
        self.HTMLInputElement.innerHTML = self.selectedDates[0];
        // if you want to hide the calendar after picking a date
        self.hide();
      } else {
        self.HTMLInputElement.textContent = '';
      }
    },
  },
  settings: {
    visibility: {
      positionToInput: 'center',
    },
  },

});

Then add the div wrapper just after your input:
<input id="calendar" type="text" placeholder="Choose date" readonly />
<div id="calendar-wrapper" style="position: relative;"></div>

And finally, use a class to set top to 0px, because Vanilla Calendar just allow to work with first init, not every time the calendar is rendered:
.top-0 {
  top: 0 !important;
}

You can check result here: https://jsfiddle.net/gf72b34L/2/
